# On second click, element gets moved to the edge of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that after I click an element(button1), expands its height. I then have another button appear which allows you to shrink the div(button2). After I click button1, the div expands and button2 shows at the bottom. I can then click button2 to shrink the div back to normal, but if I expand the div again, button2 is now off the edge of the screen, albeit in the same bottom location, just far left rather than centered.

I had to set the margin on button2 to -25px since the absolute positioning was kicking it off-center. And I need to use absolute positioning since it seemed it was only way to get the button to appear at the bottom of div after it had expanded.

```js
$(".button1").on("click", function(){

  $(".button1" ).fadeOut(200); 

  $("#block3").animate({ 
    height: '800px' 
  }, 600, function() {

    $(".button2").fadeIn(200);

  });

});



$(".button2").on("click", function(){

  $(".button2").fadeOut(200);  
  $("#block3").animate({ 
    height: '400px' 
  }, 600,function(){
    $(".button1" ).fadeIn(200);

  });

});
```

```css
.button2{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display:none; 
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.button1{

width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin-top: 25px;
image-rendering: auto;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class = "col-md-12" id = "block3">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/120x80/00aaaa/fff/?text=scroll.png"  class = "button1" />
      <img src="https://placehold.it/120x80/00aaaa/fff/?text=scroll1.png"  class = "button2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Uploaded the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/bs9xhe5e/2/

Comment: I think you are missing code and css since the snippet is not working like you described it.

Comment: I added in what was missing, but it doesn't recreate the problem I'm seeing. It might be a larger issue but I can't really post the whole website page. I wasn't sure if any of my code seemed like it would cause that issue. I was thinking it must either be the absolute positioning or the negative margin.

Comment: It's hard to tell if we can't reproduce the problem. Judging by your code it could be done much easier than what you have without absolute pos or negative margin. You need to provide a link to site for further assistance.

Comment: Ok I added a jsfiddle. If you scroll to the blue div you'll see the issue. If you have a way to improve the code I'm all ears, as I've been teaching myself everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the second click it changed the inline styling to display:block instead of display:inline, if you just add the display:inline into your jQuery it works;

https://jsfiddle.net/havL1z3m/

Added

```
$(".button2").css({display:"inline"});
```

Comment: Awesome that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason `.button2` is showing up all the way to the left is that the `absolute` positioning gives it a default `left` of `0px`.

Probably the easiest fix would be to remove `absolute` position, as well as the `margin-left`. Instead, to get `.button2` to the bottom of the section, just set `margin-top: 725px`.

```
.button2{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display:none; 
  margin-top: 725px;
}
```

And then you will no longer need to use `.css()` to change `bottom` of `.button2`.

Check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkpx7L15/

Answer (score 0):

Change button2 styles like this:

```
.button2{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display:none; 
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -25px;
   left:50%;//added style
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bs9xhe5e/3/
And everything will work fine
NOTE: Element will be positioned to the center of parent like this only when width is fixed like here. Example:

```
.someItem{
  width: someWidth;//here we set some width to element
  left: 50%; //Here we set position from the left
  margin-left: -(somewidth/2);//here we set -half of the element's width for margin-left
}
```